# How to launch Airdroid web server from adb?

Tags: android, adb, data-recovery

My Galaxy S4 screen broke - basic cellphone issue.
I have Airdroid installed and I really need to access some of my SMS and contacts informations.

My device is rooted and USB debug is enabled but I cannot adb in root mode because apparently it is not enabled in my settings :( So no access to the `/data` directory.

From `adb shell` I can launch Airdroid using `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.sand.airdroid/.ui.splash.SplashActivity_` but I don't know how to launch the webserver and accept the request from adb.

How can I access my `/data` directory or how can I launch the airdroid web server?

Thanks for any answer in advance.

EDIT: I also have TWRP installed, but `adb shell twrp mount /data` doesn't mount any partition on my linux system.

**Solution found for future reference**: `adb shell twrp backup D` and transfer the huuuuge backup on my computer using mtp. It creates a Tar archive.

Comment: Airdroid?? or Android???

Comment: Airdroid is an app used to access your device from your computer's browser. I forgot to mention that I also have access to `adb shell twrp` commands, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use adb?
It just login from http://web.airdroid.com/.

Comment: I didn't create a webacount :(